# How can i convert UIFont to CGFontRef?I causes warning and not working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

i have declared a UIFont as delegate... and in another file i'm converting that delegate UIColor to CGColorRef by

```
CGColorRef *color = appdel.color.CGColor;
```

Answer (score 26):

```
CGFontRef cgFont = CGFontCreateWithFontName((CFStringRef)uiFont.fontName);
```

Comment: doesn't take into account the font size. You need to do that manually.

Comment: This also requires a bridge if you're using ARC. Using something like the following worked for me: `CGFontRef cgFont = CGFontCreateWithFontName((__bridge CFStringRef)uiFont.fontName);`

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4 `CGFontRef` has been renamed to `CGFont`.
Conversion is pretty easy

`let font: CGFont? = CGFont(uiFont.fontName as CFString)`

Answer (score -1):

You're asking one question in the subject and it seems another in the body. I will respond to the one in the subject.

You can just simply cast a UIFont * to a CGFontRef like this:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0];
CGFontRef cgFont = (CGFontRef) font;
```

I haven't confirmed if this is the official way to do it but it works for me.

Update:

It's a bit odd cause it works sometimes but sometimes it does not. For example, this works:

```
CGContextSetFont(context, (CGFontRef) font);
```

But this does not:

```
CTFontCreateWithGraphicsFont((CGFontRef) font, 10.0, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Apple's docs for CATextLayer specifically say you cannot use a UIFont instance where a CGFontRef was requested. This begs the question whether CGFontRef/UIFont are truly toll-free bridged (I guess not?)

Comment: `CGContextSetFont(context, (CGFontRef) font)` isn't working for me either -- it silently fails, even when I add `__bridge` to make it a "bridged cast"